# Specific Minimum OpenJDK Version in RPM

Tags: dependency-management, rpm, yum

I specified a minimum OpenJDK version in an rpm called `MyPackage`.

```
# rpm -qR MyPackage
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel >= 1.8.0.161
```

I am installing the package on a machine that already has OpenJDK `1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9`.

```
# rpm -q --provides java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
...
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel = 1:1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9
```

yum installs `MyPackage` without upgrading OpenJDK to `1.8.0.161-3.b14.el6_9` and this version is available in the yum repository.

What do I need to specify in the RPM dependencies to cause OpenJDK to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum OpenJDK version in the rpm must include the `epoch`; otherwise, the `epoch` will default to 0.  Hence, this is the corrected RPM.

```
# rpm -qR MyPackage
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel >= 1:1.8.0.161
```

Comment: I concur. Great tool is rpmdev-vercmp. Try: `rpmdev-vercmp  1:1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9 1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9` which gives: `1:1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9 > 1.8.0.144-0.b01.el6_9`